# receiving json from mobile app

Tags: php, mobile

I have just started research of how to do php scripts for mobile devices and I cant find any way how to receive data.

It will receive some kind of easy json but I am not sure how to tell php to receive it. Is it same as in web using $POST_[]? or some kind of require()?

Comment: every script/language has different methods to call external URL, depends what sdk/language you are working on. Be more specific.

Comment: It depends on what technology you are using to send the JSON. It might be REST (HTTP-request), SOAP, XML-RPC, etc. What technology do you use for you mobile client?

Comment: To code the app we are using Corona SDK which is using Lua language. I insert link below http://www.anscamobile.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the same as a desktop - Ajax is no different on a mobile device. Just think of it as a browser on a smaller screen :-)

You'll want $_POST, $_REQUEST or file_get_contents("php://input");

Comment: okey so lets say that app is sending json directly to my script. I just put $myjson=$_POST['']; and then ill get that json as a string  to variable?

Comment: So say $myjson = file_get_contents("php://input"); Then json_decode that to get a php object or assoc array.